# How to defer loading of the twitter embedded timeline widget?

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm using the new twitter embedded timeline widget and by default you need to place the script at the position in the page where you want it to display.

This means it's getting called before my other scripts at the bottom of the page, some of which adjust the layout and twitter is causing quite noticeable delay

How would I go about dynamically inserting the widget at the end, after all other js has run?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search?    
q=from%3A%40jamesTbone" 
data-widget-id="XXXXXXXXXX"></a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)
[0];if(!d.getElementById(id))    
{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.async=true;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs
.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the script block at the end of the page. Jquery will run each script sequentially down the page.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. I thought the <script> had to be in the position where eyou wanted the widget to display but you're saying that the <a> element only needs to be